# Devtools CPU profiler missing from Chrome Canary 57

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

On Chrome Canary v 57.0.2949 I do not have the ability to make a cpu profile.
The tab 'profiles' has been renamed to Memory and I only see the options shown in the screenshot below. The feature on the Profiles tab was called "Record JavaScript CPU Profile".

Trying console.profile also does not add an entry in the profiler...

Is this only me or what would be causing this type of problem?
[only options in profiler/memory tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eCaC.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug. It was intentionally removed because it was largely redundant with the Performance panel.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration

Comment: Okay that clarifies a lot and solves part of the problem. What to do then with the console.profile function calls. Any equivalent for that? I use it to create a cpu profile for snippets that I run. How can I do this now?

Comment: Looks like the team forgot about that edge case. Bug filed: https://crbug.com/675734